# iPad Map Screen Resolution stuck at 1024x768

Tags: swift, xcode6

Not sure if this is a Swift / Xcode6 or iOS question but that's my environment.  I have an iOS Swift map app that works fine in terms of the iOS simulator and iPhone devices but when I use any of iPad devices in the simulator or actual devices the MapView is stuck at 1024x768 so it only uses a portion of the screen (upper right) on the iPad.

I dumped out the Screen Bounds, View Bounds and View Frame width and height and they are all set to this default value of 1024x768 and all origins set to 0,0.  How do I get it to utilize the full screen of an iPad device? I thought that the Screen values would be set according to the device, simulator or real and I could reset off of those but I can't seem to figure it out.   Also wondering if this is something that can be set in the Storyboard for the MKMapView in terms of scale settings or something.

So the question is how do I get things to behave and use full screen for iPad devices.

Here's the sample code, very simple, to dump out these values

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var theMapView : MKMapView

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    println("myscreen.bounds.width, height = \(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width) \(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height) ")
    println("self.view.bounds.width, height = \(self.view.bounds.width) \(self.view.bounds.height) ")
    println("self.view.bounds.origin x,y = \(self.view.bounds.origin.x) \(self.view.bounds.origin.y) ")
    println("self.view.frame.width, height = \(self.view.frame.width)  \(self.view.frame.height) ")
    println("self.view.frame.origin.x,y = \(self.view.frame.origin.x) \(self.view.frame.origin.y) ")
}
```

and the output results:

```
myscreen.bounds.width, height = 768.0 1024.0 
self.view.bounds.width, height = 768.0 1024.0 
self.view.bounds.origin x,y = 0.0 0.0 
self.view.frame.width, height = 768.0  1024.0 
self.view.frame.origin.x,y = 0.0 0.0
```

[image: Simulator or Device Screenshot]

Comment: It looks like an autolayout constraints issue in storyboard (and not related to Swift/MKMapView/Xcode6).

Comment: Yes it was.... another lesson learned today about the need to manage the constraints our of the box just for the iPad output but not the iPhone.  Not sure I get that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the screenshot it looks like you've used the new universal storyboard, put in a map view while editing in Any/Any mode, and not set constraints. Because there are no constraints telling the map view to stick to the edges of its superview, it remains the size of the Any/Any Interface Builder canvas.

In your storyboard, select the map view and choose Reset to Suggested Constraints from the little I-beam popup menu in the lower right.

(The numbers you're printing aren't telling the whole story because you're printing the screen size and the container view size, but not the size  of `theMapView`.)

Comment: That was the trick...TKS.  I don't really understand why or it isn't that way by default. The printout of theMapView before and after the fix the and the results stayed the same which has me more confused..  the results before and after for the iPad and it remained as follows:       myscreen.bounds.width, height = 768.0 1024.0 
self.view.bounds.width, height = 768.0 1024.0 
self.view.frame.width, height = 768.0  1024.0 
self.theMapview.bounds.width, height = 240.0 128.0 
self.theMapview.frame.width, height = 240.0  128.0

Comment: I have another issue in that in my main program (not this subset test) I somehow broke the iPhone output in the simulator and on device in that it just shows a white canvas instead of the map.  This was after futile attempts before this fix to try different things in the storyboard.  I applied this fix on constraints but the iPhone output remains blank.  I don't see anywhere where device specific output should come into play.  I posted that here [link to that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567419/map-not-showing-on-iphone-simulator-but-does-for-ipad)